# SqlBulkCopy with SqlHelper class

Tags: c#, sqlbulkcopy, data-access, sqlhelper

I've installed `DataAccessApplicationBlock.msi` and I got the `Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.dll` file into my bin folder. I found every other sqlhelper methods except `ExecuteBulkCopy`.

How do I add `ExecuteBulkCopy` function to the `SqlHelper` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't that block an *abstraction* over the database? What would the code do if it wasn't SQL-Server? I personally don't think it makes *sense* to encapsulate this in a general-purpose (and database-neutral) library.

Also; it is pretty basic functionality, so you shouldn't have any problem writing a method for the basic scenario that accepts a connection-string, table name, and `IDataReader` / `DataTable`. In non-trivial usage is has lots of configuration options (column mapping, events, etc), and probably doesn't warrant wrapping.

To be honest, while I *use* `SqlBulkCopy`, I don't use it often enough (or similarly enough) to warrant hiding it away. Perhaps just use `SqlBulkCopy` directly in your repository / DAL / whatever code?